# how do I check if there is a particular 'tag' in a mysql field?

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

The question and the following, I have a small code that checks if a particular 'tag' exists in a table field I tried to do as follows:

```
<?php
$value = "e-sports";

$test = array();
$take = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM news WHERE game LIKE '%$value%' OR tags LIKE '%$value%' ");

while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($take)) {

    $test[] = $info['tags']; 

    if (in_array($value, $test)) {
        echo "ok";
    }else{ 
        echo "not";
    }
}
?>
```

but that did not work out.
I would like to know if it has a better shape, or something to use instead.

Comment: In what way did it not work out?

Comment: Do not give me a result

Comment: If it didn't echo "ok" or "not" then it means your query returned no results.

Comment: `checks if a particular 'tag' exists in a table` why don't you compare only `tags` without `game`?

Comment: I've a solution without using while loop

Comment: What's the content of `news`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `tags` column of your database is some kind of list containing multiple tags, e.g. `'tag1,tag2,tag3'`, so your solution and Rod Elias's solution won't work by doing a simple string comparison.

Instead you should explode the string into an array and then search that. Set the value of `$tagseparator` to be whatever is dividing the tags in the db.

```
<?php
$value = "e-sports";
$tagseparator = ",";

$test = array();
$take = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM news WHERE game LIKE '%$value%' OR tags LIKE '%$value%' ");

while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($take)) {
    foreach(explode($tagseparator,$info['tags']) as $tag) {
        $test[] = $tag;
    }
}

if (in_array($value, $test)) {
    echo "ok";
} else { 
    echo "not";
}
?>
```

Note that if you want to check on a row-by-row basis rather than in the entire result set you would just change the test to

```
while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($take)) {
    $test = explode($tagseparator,$info['tags']);
    if (in_array($value, $test)) {
        echo "ok";
    } else { 
        echo "not";
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked out, I really wanted to check line by line. thank you so much

Comment: Use the second loop at the bottom for line-by-line.

Comment: Yes, I saw you put it on. thank you very much, it really was worth it, I was trying to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply do:

```
if ($info['tags'] == $value) {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'not';
}
```

?

Answer (score -1):

I've a solution without using while loop

```
$value = "e-sports";    
$test = array();
$take = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM news WHERE game LIKE '%$value%' OR tags LIKE '%$value%' ");
//$take = [['id'=> 1, "tags" => "e-sports", "game" => "lol"],
         //['id'=> 2, "tags" => "mobile", "game" => "lol"],
         //['id'=> 3, "tags" => "xbox", "game" => "abc"]];
$filter = array_filter( $take , function($v, $k) use ($value){
    return $v["tags"] == $value;
} , ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
if(sizeof($filter) > 0){
    echo 'yes';
}else{
    echo 'not';
}
```

Comment: I'm going to test here, thank you very much for the help

Comment: This requires the user to load the entire table into memory via `fetch_all()` prior to calling the filter function, which you have not made clear. Additionally, the `array_filter()` function is effectively a for loop, so you achieve no computational savings whilst incurring significant additional memory cost.

Comment: not use `fetch_all()` the query still  `$take = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM news WHERE game LIKE '%$value%' OR tags LIKE '%$value%' ");` 
`$take` array below just an example

Comment: you use alot of connection to db via `mysqli_query` , and alot of `mysqli_fetch_array` in while loop